# extracting google map link from database

Tags: c#, google-maps

I stored the link of specific address of googlemap in database and tried to extract in literal using the following function:

```
public void BindData()
{
    string Id = Request.QueryString["id"];
   // int Id = 1;
    main obj = new main();
    DataTable dt = obj.GetData("select map from mandir where id= '" + Id + "'");
    string path = dt.Rows[0]["map"].ToString();
    lit1.Text = obj.GetGooglemap(path);
    //rptMarkers.DataSource = dt;
    //rptMarkers.DataBind();

}
```

I am just getting the link but not the map.Can anyone suggest me what is wrong?

Comment: Is it the full folder path or just the file name? Can you share a sample of the result

Comment: @Damien I got the result like this:       https://maps.google.com/maps?q=Pashupatinath+Temple,+Kathmandu,+Central+Region,+Nepal&hl=en&ll=27.710412,85.348771&

Comment: in your code you are binding the map path to the text property of a literal (I believe). So it would just show you a path. Which API are you using to show the maps?